# Exporting a list of 2x2 tables from R to excel

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have a dataset that contains a number of YES/NO variables (A, B, C, etc.) for every observation, i.e.:

```
  Type   A    B   C    D   E
1   A1 YES  YES  NO  YES YES
2   A2  NO  YES  NO <NA> YES
3   A2 YES <NA>  NO   NO YES
4   A1 YES   NO YES   NO  NO
```

Each observation is one of two types (A1 or A2). Some some observations do not include certain variables ("NA").

My goal is to create a series 2x2 contingency tables that compare both types for each variable, and then to export these tables to Excel.

After some research I was able to make the tables using lapply:

```
Tables = lapply(Data[2:6], table, Data$Type)
```

This produces a list of tables for each variable, e.g.:

```
$A

    A1 A2
NO   0  1
YES  2  1

$B

    A1 A2
NO   1  0
YES  1  1
```

etc.

However, I have no idea about how to export this list of tables into a format that excel can read. Obviously my aim is to export each element of each table (A, NO, YES, A1, 0, 1, etc.) into a separate spreadsheet cell.

How do I do this?

Till now my search for a solution has only thrown up pages suggesting using lapply in conjunction with write.csv, something like:

```
lapply(Tables, write.csv, "Tables.csv")
```

But that just produces a .csv with a single table:

```
    A1  A2
NO  1   0
YES 1   2
```

Any help would be most welcome, I have about 500 of these 2x2 tables that I need to make from my actual data and get into excel. Apologies if I am missing something very basic here, I am brand new to R.

Comment: You are rewriting the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `lapply` function does not "know" (or have available) the names of the items that are attached to its values, sometimes it is more convenient to pass the names and access the values inside the function. Try this:

```
lapply(names(Tables), function(t) write.csv(Tables[[t]], file=paste0(t,".csv") ))  
 #Ignore the list of "NULL"'s
```

This is the value I see with a text editor in the `A.csv file:

```
"","A1","A2"
"NO",0,1
"YES",2,1
```

Comment: That is starting to get better, it is certainly the correct figures being output! But is there any way to export them all as a single .csv file?

Comment: Just omit the `t` argument to `write.csv`, put some desired character value  in it's place and use the `append=TRUE` parameter.